# HTML5 Scortable sorting and making ajax call to change the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html5sortable

I been working on a todo app to learn. I built a todo app with state on rails. it looks like this

[image]

I had a button to change the state of the tasks. But i want to make drag and drop. So i been tinkering with the html5 sortable library. I got to draging and dropping within the task state, meaning dragging and dropping within todo, or in progress or done. But i can't drag and drop between the states and change to the respective state.

I need help understanding rather than just guide on how to do it. i have attached my codes below,

**controller**

```
def change
    @task.update_attributes(state: params[:state])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_path, notice: 'Task updated' }
    end
end
```

View

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 sortable1"><h2 class="text-center">Todo</h2>
    <% @to_do.each do |task| %>
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 sortable2"><h2 class="text-center">In Progress</h2>
    <% @in_progress.each do |task| %>
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-4 sortable3"><h2 class="text-center">Done</h2>
    <% @done.each do |task| %>
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :tasks do
    member do
      put :change
    end
  end
```

**Javascript**

```
var ready;
var id = $(this).attr("id");
ready = function(){
    // call sortable on our div with the sortable class
    $('.sortable1').sortable();
    $('.sortable2').sortable();
    $('.sortable3').sortable();
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '/tasks/' + id + '/change',
        data: { order: updated_order }
    });
}

$(document).ready(ready);
/**
 * if using turbolinks
 */
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**UPDATE**

Got it working to move to next state like this

**Javascript**

```
var ready;
var id = $(this).attr("task_id");
ready = function(){
    // call sortable on our div with the sortable class
    $('#sortable1').sortable(
      {
      connectWith: ".connected"
    }
    );
    $('#sortable2').sortable({
      connectWith: ".connected"
    });
    $('#sortable3').sortable({
      connectWith: ".connected"
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '/tasks/' + id + '/change'
    });
}

$(document).ready(ready);
/**
 * if using turbolinks
 */
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4"><h2 class="text-center">Todo</h2>
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connected sortable list">
    <% @to_do.each do |task| %>
    <li>
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" task-id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4"><h2 class="text-center">In Progress</h2>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connected sortable list">
    <% @in_progress.each do |task| %>
    <li>
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" task-id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-4"><h2 class="text-center">Done</h2>
    <ul id="sortable3" class="connected sortable list">
    <% @done.each do |task| %>
    <li>
    <div class="<%= task.state == 'to_do' ? 'card card-outline-info' : task.state == 'in_progress' ? 'card card-outline-success' : 'card card-outline-warning'  %>" style="max-width: 20rem;" task-id="<%= task.id %>">
      <div class="card-header action-box">
        <div class="text-xs-left">
          <strong><%= link_to task.title, edit_task_path(task)%></strong>
        </div>
          <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    <%end%>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it wont go to the next ul if the ul doesn't have empty list, it just moves only if the ul of other state already has a li item

Comment: And exactly what is `$(this).attr("id")` in that context ?

Comment: not sure, i am trying to get the id for the ajax request later